# Plot Histogram in Python

Tags: python, frequency, histogram

I have two lists, x and y.
x contains the alphabet A-Z and Y contains the frequency of them in a file.

I've tried researching how to plot these values in a histogram but has had no success with understanding how to plot it.

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 26, normed=1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.75)
```

Would x be list x in the lists mentioned above?

Comment: There's not even a question mark in your question. But check out matplotlib.

Answer (score 50):

`hist` works on a collection of values and computes and draws the histogram from them.
In your case you already precalculated the frequency of each group (letter). To represent your data in an histogram form use better matplotlib `bar`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alphab = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
frequencies = [23, 44, 12, 11, 2, 10]

pos = np.arange(len(alphab))
width = 1.0     # gives histogram aspect to the bar diagram

ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xticks(pos + (width / 2))
ax.set_xticklabels(alphab)

plt.bar(pos, frequencies, width, color='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That `+ (width / 2)` thing is deprecated. Just use `ax.set_xticks(pos)`.