# Plotting frequency distribution/histogram with frequency table

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plot

I'm familiar with the matplotlib histogram reference:

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist

However, I don't actually have the original series/data to pass into the plot. I have only the summary statistics in a DataFrame. Example:

`df`

```
lower  upper  occurrences  frequency
0.0    0.5    17           .111
0.5    0.1    65           .426
0.1    1.5    147          .963
1.5    2.0    210          1.376
.
.
.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926061/plot-histogram-in-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393959/r-histogram-from-frequency-table

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to calculate a histogram here, because you already have the histogrammed data. Therefore you may simply plot a bar chart.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df.lower, df.occurences, width=df.upper-df.lower, ec="k", align="edge")
```